# How to read the content of an online PDF file into a string variable using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, automation

I am wondering if anyone has dealt with this before. I have a spreadsheet with links to thousands of pdf files. I would like to load the content of each pdf into a string variable and run a few RegEx to extract useful data. I have the function shown below which loads the content of a pdf file into a string, however this function only works for local files. However in my case I am opening the pdf file using `IE.Navigate2 "https://www.example.com/mypdf.pdf"` this will open the pdf in the browser, how can I load the content of that file into a string. The extreme solution would be to download the file and open it with the function below and then delete it. Please let me know your thoughts. Please note that the function below will only work if you have Acrobat installed (not the reader) you will also will need to add the reference in the VBA project to Adobe Acrobat Type Library

```
Public Function ReadAcrobatDocument(strFileName As String) As String
    Dim AcroApp As CAcroApp, AcroAVDoc As CAcroAVDoc, AcroPDDoc As CAcroPDDoc
    Dim AcroHiliteList As CAcroHiliteList, AcroTextSelect As CAcroPDTextSelect
    Dim PageNumber, PageContent, Content, i, j
    Set AcroApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
    Set AcroAVDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")
    If AcroAVDoc.Open(strFileName, vbNull) <> True Then Exit Function
    ' The following While-Wend loop shouldn't be necessary but timing issues may occur.
    While AcroAVDoc Is Nothing
      Set AcroAVDoc = AcroApp.GetActiveDoc
    Wend
    Set AcroPDDoc = AcroAVDoc.GetPDDoc
    For i = 0 To AcroPDDoc.GetNumPages - 1
      Set PageNumber = AcroPDDoc.AcquirePage(i)
      Set PageContent = CreateObject("AcroExch.HiliteList")
      If PageContent.Add(0, 9000) <> True Then Exit Function
      Set AcroTextSelect = PageNumber.CreatePageHilite(PageContent)
      ' The next line is needed to avoid errors with protected PDFs that can't be read
      On Error Resume Next
      For j = 0 To AcroTextSelect.GetNumText - 1
        Content = Content & AcroTextSelect.GetText(j)
      Next j
    Next i
    ReadAcrobatDocument = Content
    AcroAVDoc.Close True
    AcroApp.Exit
    Set AcroAVDoc = Nothing: Set AcroApp = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: It would be faster to download the file since there is no rendering involved. I don't see any gain in extracting the PDF with the browser, only pain.

Comment: I agree! Only pain